# Db2 blob upload file

Tags: c#, db2, oledb

i trying to upload file into table with blob colomun. It works, but not correct, can help?
this code upload, but not correct. When i open table i see this |ID=1|File_Z=COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Blob@54c6c724|

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(textBox4.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            byte[] file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

            reader.Close();
            stream.Close();
            string query = "UPDATE UPDATE_Z SET FILE_Z=? WHERE ID='"+1+"';";

            {
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conn);
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                // command.CreateParameter();

                command.CommandText = query;

                command.Parameters.Add("FILE_Z", OleDbType.Binary, file.Length);
                command.Parameters[0].Value = file;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
               // for (int i=0; i < file.Length;i++ )
                //{
                  // MessageBox.Show(file[i].ToString());
                //}

            }
            query = "SELECT FILE_Z FROM UPDATE_Z where ID ='"+1+"'";
            FileStream stream1;
            BinaryWriter writer;

            int bufferSize = 100;
            byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize];

            long retval;
            long startIndex = 0;

            string pubID = "";


            OleDbConnection connection1 = new OleDbConnection(conn);
            connection1.Open();
            OleDbCommand command1 = connection1.CreateCommand();
            command1.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default);



            while (reader1.Read())
            {
             //   pubID = reader1.GetString(0);

                stream1 = new FileStream("version1.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                writer = new BinaryWriter(stream1);
                startIndex = 0;
               retval = reader1.GetBytes(0, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);

                while (retval == bufferSize)
                {
                    writer.Write(outByte);
                    writer.Flush();
                    startIndex += bufferSize;
                    retval = reader1.GetBytes(0, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
                }
                writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval - 1);
                writer.Flush();

                writer.Close();

                stream1.Close();
            }

            reader1.Close();
            connection1.Close();
```

And output file "ZAP.EXE" size is 0 kb, but byte array file is not empty....

Comment: Your method is doing too much.  Start by separating this out into smaller methods (switching to local variables), in an attempt to reduce this to the smallest reproduceable section.  Is nothing being returned from the reader?  Can you write _anything_ to the file?

Comment: noting returned. I think problem is in writing to the database... i doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know... break things apart like I said, and investigate what command actually gets executed.  Perhaps the fact that you add a parameter before attaching the command text is a problem?  At minimum, writing to the output file has an obvious issue, if the contents of the file don't even contain the text of the database (open it in Notepad or a hex editor).

Comment: it works, but output file less than inpt on 1 byte...

Comment: Clockwork-Muse, thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(textBox4.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            byte[] file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

            reader.Close();
            stream.Close();
            string query = "UPDATE UPDATE_Z SET FILE_Z=? WHERE ID='"+1+"';";

            {
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conn);
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                // command.CreateParameter();

                command.CommandText = query;

                command.Parameters.Add("FILE_Z", OleDbType.Binary, file.Length);
                command.Parameters[0].Value = file;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
               // for (int i=0; i < file.Length;i++ )
                //{
                  // MessageBox.Show(file[i].ToString());
                //}

            }
            query = "SELECT FILE_Z FROM UPDATE_Z where ID ='"+1+"'";
            FileStream stream1;
            BinaryWriter writer;

            int bufferSize = 100;
            byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize];

            long retval;
            long startIndex = 0;

            string pubID = "";


            OleDbConnection connection1 = new OleDbConnection(conn);
            connection1.Open();
            OleDbCommand command1 = connection1.CreateCommand();
            command1.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataReader reader1 = command1.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default);



            while (reader1.Read())
            {
             //   pubID = reader1.GetString(0);

                stream1 = new FileStream("version1.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                writer = new BinaryWriter(stream1);
                startIndex = 0;
               retval = reader1.GetBytes(0, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);

                while (retval == bufferSize)
                {
                    writer.Write(outByte);
                    writer.Flush();
                    startIndex += bufferSize;
                    retval = reader1.GetBytes(0, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
                }
                writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval);
                writer.Flush();

                writer.Close();

                stream1.Close();
            }

            reader1.Close();
            connection1.Close();
```

The problem was that this code  `writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval - 1);` 
lost last byte from file and file was not full, i have no idea what for this line of code need...

Comment: While answering your own question is certainly acceptable, you should at least put an explanation as to _why_ this fixed the problem.  What made your original code incorrect?